# UISearchBar Height not resizing

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar that I need to be rather large (height of 68px).  I have tried resizing from the source code of the xib as well as changing the subview of UITextField from UISearchbar, neither fixed the issue (pictured below):

Tried setting appearance (everything worked except height change):

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:48]];
UITextField *searchField = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
searchField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
searchField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
searchField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
CGRect searchFieldRect = searchField.frame;
searchFieldRect.size.height = 100;
searchField.frame = searchFieldRect;
```

[image: Result:]

Answer (score 1):

Just used a UITextField with the text field notifications to judge when text had changed and called my Search methods.